# Android - Open Spinner Programmatically (dialog spinner)

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner which's `spinnerMode` is dialog. My question is: How can I open it programmatically by a button click or anything else? `performClick()` didn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

```
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

Comment: `button.setOnClickListener` should work.

Comment: what did `performClick()` method return?

Answer (score 4):

I Hope this will work for you.

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                        R.array.your_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //add your arraylist.
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.performClick();

            }
        });
```

Comment: When using a dialog my spinner gets open behind the dialog using performClick(); Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

**I tried below code in my MainActivity.class it works like a charm!**

*Code:*

```
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    String[] list={"one","Two","one","Two","one","Two","one","Two"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.performClick();
```

Note:Place this "spinner.performClick();" where ever you required ie,on button click or on server response etc....

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for spinner

```
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

    ArrayList<String> listSPinner = new ArrayList<>();
    listSPinner.add("1");
    listSPinner.add("1");
    listSPinner.add("1");
    listSPinner.add("1");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSPinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```